# Add an action to user register form

Tags: users, forms

On registration I want to get the value of the user's email and forward them to a page that has an option to resend their activation email.
I have the page with the form they're forwarded to, but I need some place to add the user's email address to a $session variable when user_register is being submitted. Apparently there is no submit_hook for that form without overriding it entirely (which I would rather not do).

This is the code I have so far:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    global $user;

    if($form_id=='user_register_form' && $user->uid != 1 && !in_array('manager', array_values($user->roles)))
    {
        $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = 'Create Account';
        $form['account']['mail']['#description'] = "Please use a valid email address as you will need to verify it.";
        $form['account']['mail']['#attributes'] = array('placeholder' => 'email@address.com');
        $form['account']['mail']['#title'] = 'Email Address';
        $form['account']['name']['#description'] = "";

        $form['#action'] .= '?destination=node/'.variable_get('checkemailpage', 6);

    }
}
```

Comment: If the answer helped you, you should accept it. If not, there may need to be some clarification.

Answer (score 3):

You can add additional submit callback function to the registration form, then assign user's email to a session so you can call it on the destination page.

Add the following line after `$form['#action']`

`$form['#submit'][] = 'custom_user_register_submit';`

Then add this function to your custom module

```
function custom_user_register_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {

  $_SESSION['custom_user_mail'] = $form_state['values']['mail'];  
}
```

Then call `$_SESSION['custom_user_mail']` on any page you want.